# How is "slaad" pronounced?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, pronunciation

Is there any official pronunciation guideline for how to pronounce "slaad"?

Comment: According to my brain every time I read it, it is pronounced "salad".

Comment: Hahaha @Rubiksmoose I play D&D in english but english is not my first language and my brain still hears "salad" instead of "slaad", no matter how hard the person tries to not say that.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose It does depend, somewhat, if they are being thrown around by a barbarian.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Dragon #93* (1985) includes the article "Ay pronunseeAYshun gyd", written by Frank Mentzer, which has guidance on how to pronounce the names of a vast array of monsters from 1e AD&D, including Slaad (the article has notable errors regarding how to pronounce some genuine English words, but can probably taken to be authoritative on its made up ones). The Forgotten Realms wiki article on [Slaad](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Slaad) includes that guidance in IPA notation, there apparently being two accepted pronunciations:

> pronounced: /slæd/ slæd or: /slɑːd/ slad

The 2e resource *Monstrous Compendium - Outer Planes Appendix* also includes pronunciation guides for its monsters in its index, giving:

> slaad (SLAHD)

If D&D Beyond counts as official, lots of the monster entries include VO of someone pronouncing their name - the core Monster Manual entries are voiced by Matt Mercer and Marisha Ray of *Critical Role*. The sound bites can be played by clicking the speaker icon next to the monster's name on their page and seem (to my ear at least) to agree with the suggested pronunciation of the prior resources.

- [Death Slaad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/death-slaad)
- [Gray Slaad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gray-slaad)
- [Green Slaad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/green-slaad)
- [Blue Slaad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/blue-slaad)
- [Red Slaad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/red-slaad)

[This ENWorld forum post](https://www.enworld.org/threads/d-d-pronunciation-guide.661505/) dug up by [V2Blast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/33569/v2blast) is a useful compilation of various official pronunciation guidelines from D&D resources.

Comment: The Mentzner article should be taken with a grain of salt, since it advocated pronouncing Pleistocene as "plee-IS-to-seen". There were other objectively incorrect entries, but that's the one that has stuck in my head since 1985.

Comment: [This ENWorld forum post](https://www.enworld.org/threads/d-d-pronunciation-guide.661505/) compiles pronunciations listed in a number of sources, including the Dragon #93 article you've cited; it also cites the MC8 Monstrous Compendium Outer Planes Appendix (for AD&D 2e) as giving the pronunciation "slahd".